# Quasilinear equation and their properties.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Show that the quasilinear differential equation 
>   $$u_y+a(u)u_x=0$$
>   with the initial condition $u(x,0)=h(x)$ has the implicit solution
>   $$u=h(x-a(u)y)$$
>   Show that there exists some positive $y$ such that $u$ is not differentiable at $y$, except if $a(h(s))$ is non-increasing.

The first part is just a calculation but I don't see how to do the second part. Can anybody give a hint?

Thanks!

Comment: My approach would be to go back to the characteristic equation.

Comment: can you extend your comment? I tried that way and I did not see anything.

Comment: I actually show that you will have shock only if $a(h(s))$ is decreasing, are you sure your question is correct? I don't know what notation you use, but try and compare with your own ones: from the three characteristic equations, substituting $y=t$ into the expression for $x=a(u)t+s$, you will get an expression for $y$. Note that for fixed $s$, the characteristic is simply a straight line parallel to the $x-y$ plane. For $a(u)=a(h(s))$ increasing on some interval, your characteristics will not meet, thus there is no shock. For the other case, you have shock, which is a discontinuity.

Comment: The idea is that you want to prove that shock occurs under certain condition, and the only place you can extract information is from the characteristic equations itself since that is what you only have. I haven't solve PDEs for quite some time, I apologise if my explanation is a little vague. Your question seems like a generalisation of the Burger's equation, so try and understand that and you should be able to extend the argument to your equation of interest here :)

Comment: You have give me some good ideas. If I got something I will post it here.

Comment: Glad I could help, keep me posted.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the method in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example:

$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=1$ , letting $y(0)=0$ , we have $y=t$

$\dfrac{du}{dt}=0$ , letting $u(0)=u_0$ , we have $u=u_0$

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=a(u)=a(u_0)$ , letting $x(0)=f(u_0)$ , we have $x=a(u_0)t+f(u_0)=a(u)y+f(u)$ , i.e. $u=F(x-a(u)y)$

$u(x,0)=h(x)$ :

$F(x)=h(x)$

$\therefore u=h(x-a(u)y)$